# Same iTunes, different iTunes! (whishlist shortcut disappeared!)

Tags: itunes

In iTunes I have my whishlist, sometimes I go to check that searching special prices. Since last iTunes version, I used to click on my username and use the shortcut to see my whishlist. With last update I noticed (with lot of disappoint!) that this shortcut disappeared!

[image]

Then I went on my other Mac and I noticed that here the shortcut survived!

[image]

What could be the difference?

Comment: I still can access the wishlist etc in 12.3.3.17. Did you try to log out and log in within iTunes?

Comment: I've just found the solution! (I don't know why) It depends from Apple Music, seems that, from this last update, to have that shortcut, Apple Music must be enabled in iTunes's settings.

Comment: Oh! Please post this as an answer below (and accept it once the grace period has passed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From (or, I hope, in) iTunes version 12.3.3.17, to show that shortcut, is necessary to enable "Show Apple Music" in iTunes's settings.

[image]